# Range Selector - Changing bar color only when active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a price slider I have created that changes the price and amount of items being used depending which span you click in the slider:

```css
.price-slider {
  margin-bottom: 29px;
  width: 254px;
}
.price-slider .slider-count {
  font-size: 13px!important;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 3px;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc.price-slider-disc-2 {
  left: 28px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc.price-slider-disc-3 {
  left: 60px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc.price-slider-disc-4 {
  left: 92px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc .price-slider-disc-5 {
  left: 124px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc.price-slider-disc-6 {
  left: 156px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc.price-slider-disc-7 {
  left: 188px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc.price-slider-disc-8 {
  left: 220px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc.price-slider-disc-9 {
  left: 252px;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .price-slider-disc.price-slider-disc-active {
  background-color: #54d8a3;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-bar .slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 19px;
  width: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  z-index: 1;
}
.price-slider .price-slider-box .price-slider-range {
  background-color: #54d8a3;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-slider">
  <h2 class="slider-count"><span class="js-slider-count" data-count="starter">100</span> items/month</h2> <!-- HERE --> 
  <div class="price-slider-box">
    <div class="price-slider-bar">
      <span data-option="starter" data-price-value="24" data-count-value="100" class="price-slider-disc price-slider-disc-2 price-slider-disc-active"></span>
      <span data-option="starter" data-price-value="30" data-count-value="200" class="price-slider-disc price-slider-disc-3"></span>
      <span data-option="starter" data-price-value="40" data-count-value="300" class="price-slider-disc price-slider-disc-4"></span>
      <span data-option="starter" data-price-value="50" data-count-value="400" class="price-slider-disc price-slider-disc-5"></span>
      <span data-option="starter" data-price-value="60" data-count-value="500" class="price-slider-disc price-slider-disc-6"></span>
      <span data-option="starter" data-price-value="70" data-count-value="600" class="price-slider-disc price-slider-disc-7"></span>
      <span data-option="starter" data-price-value="80" data-count-value="700" class="price-slider-disc price-slider-disc-8"></span>
      <span data-option="starter" data-price-value="90" data-count-value="800" class="price-slider-disc price-slider-disc-9"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'm using this script to achieve that result:

```
 $('[data-option]').click(function () {
   var type = this.getAttribute('data-option');
   var value = this.getAttribute('data-price-value');
   var count = this.getAttribute('data-count-value');

   var priceContainer = document.querySelector('[data-price="' + type + '"]');
   var countContainer = document.querySelector('[data-count="' + type + '"]');
   if (typeof priceContainer !== 'undefined' && priceContainer !== null) {
     priceContainer.innerHTML = value;
   }

   if (typeof countContainer !== 'undefined' && countContainer !== null) {
     countContainer.innerHTML = count;
   }

   var options = document.querySelectorAll('[data-option="' + type + '"]');
   for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
     if (options[i].getAttribute('data-price-value') <= value) {
       $(options[i]).addClass('price-slider-disc-active');
     } else {
       $(options[i]).removeClass('price-slider-disc-active');
     }
   }
 });
```

However, I'm having a hard time getting the bar behind the spans to change color when a span is selected. I have tried adding an active class to it but it just makes the entire bar green, what I would like is for the bar to the left of the selected span to be the green color and any bar ahead of it to the right stays the grey. How can I achieve this without using the active class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use a pseudo element to mimic the line. Currently that bar is one solid bar with no breaks so you would have to create a bar inbetween the elements to make it look like its selected:

https://jsfiddle.net/5r0n62yg/1/

```
.price-slider-disc-active::before {
  width: 21px;
  height: 3px;
  background: green;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -21px;
  top: 5px;
  content:'';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('[data-option]').click(function () {
    $(this).css('color','green');
}
```